# Opening files in the same folder as the current file, in vim

Tags: unix, vim, vi

In vim, when I have a buffer open, I often need to load another file in the same directory that file is in, but since I don't usually `cd` into it, the `pwd` is a parent folder, so I have to retype the path every time. Is there a shortcut for this? or a way to change the pwd to the directory the file is in?

example:

```
cd /src
vi lib/foo/file.js
```

*lib/foo* has two files: `file.js` and `file2.js`

in vi:

```
:e file2.js  # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Newer versions of vim have a autochdir command built in, if not you can fall back to a BufEnter like setup.

```
" set vim to chdir for each file
if exists('+autochdir')
    set autochdir
else
    autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h:gs/ /\\ /
endif
```

Comment: If you're going to do this then why not just `cd` to that directory in the first place before opening the file. They're both equally restrictive in terms of accessing other directories after the file is opened? @hgmnz solution below is far more elegant & flexible.

Answer (score 77):

:Ex  short for :Explore does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest answer with a working solution.

Comment: Does this let you create a new file?

Comment: Press % when in Ex and it will ask you for a new file. @JacobSharf

Comment: I prefer `:Sex`

Comment: :Sex is great, :Vex is perhaps even better

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about opening a file not a directory

Comment: @SzymonWygnański you can open files that way, just type in the file path

Comment: @sumek does not seam to work with vim nor in nvim. `:Explore filename` does nothing

Comment: @SzymonWygnański just confirmed that it works with homebrew installed neovim 0.7.2 on macOS with no config

Answer (score 64):

I have the following three lines on my `.vimrc`:

```
map ,e :e <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>
map ,t :tabe <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>
map ,s :split <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>
```

Now `,e <some-file>` opens  on this buffer. `,t` and `,s` do the same but on a new tab/split window.

Comment: This is my favourite of the solutions posted here. I don't like the idea of changing to the directory of the current file automatically. I prefer to open vim in the root directory of a project, and that means that `:e` always drills down from the top. Up until now, if I wanted to open a file in the same directory as the current file, I would use `:E` which brings up the netrw file explorer. Using your `,e` mapping feels much quicker. It's great how you can tab through the files in the current directory.

Comment: Agree with you. Also, if I never have to change directory, there's always `:cd %:h`

Comment: I've used this for two days and I'm not sure how I worked without it. Great tip.

Comment: If you don't want to use the full file path including the home dir, use `%:h` instead of `%:p:h`, ie. `map ,e :e <C-R>=expand("%:h") . "/" <CR>`

Answer (score 28):

A simple idea is to use the autochdir setting.  Try this in your .vimrc:

```
set autochdir
```

This will change the working directory of vim to the directory of the file you opened.

Note: I'm not sure what version added this feature.  I updated from vim 6 to 7.2 to get this to work.

Comment: It's only available if Vim was built with netbeans integration or Sun visual workshop integration.  The former is more common than the latter, but it's not unusual to have neither builtin.  This is why gregf's answer tests for the existence of a working 'autochdir' option.

Comment: autochdir is also a pain because it switches directories before trying to load the file, so if on the command line you do `gvim path/to/file.c` it'll cd into path/to and then try to open path/to/file.c, giving you an empty buffer in a non-existent location.  :(  (64-bit 7.2 on Windows, anyway.)

Comment: This is life changing.

Answer (score 25):

Try the following:

```
:e %:p:h/file2.js
```

Comment: this is the shortest answer with the most general solution. learning about `%:p:h/` as a shortcut for the current path, helps to apply it to any other situation where the current path can be needed, like `:r`, `:w`, ...

Comment: `:sp %:h/file2.js` also seems to work. Alternatively, one can do `:sp %<tab>` and then edit the filename as needed.

Comment: it seems %:p:h is the absolute path while %:h is the relative path to the directory of the current file

Answer (score 13):

Add this line to your `vimrc` configuration

```
autocmd BufEnter * cd %:p:h
```

%               current file name
:p              expand to full path
:h              head (last path component removed)

See `:help expand` for further information.

Comment: That works great, thanks. Now to learn what this `%:p:h` means :)

Comment: This site helps me a lot when looking up vim-stuff: http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

Comment: Just be aware that this functionality may break plugins, as noted in ":help 'autochdir'".

Answer (score 6):

The solution with autochdir has its own pitfalls. For example you have to stay at the dir you are because Tags are defined with relative path or you need Makefile or pom.xml in the current dir.

You can use

```
:e <C-R>%
```

and then modify path by deleting name of the current file and enter new one.
Or.
Use the map

```
nnoremap <leader>e :edit <C-R>=fnamemodify(@%, ':p:h')<CR>/
```

And then by pressing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (depends on leader settings) you will receive command that open directory in which your current file is and you can complete this command manually and can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to show all files from the current file directory.

Or.
You can try [0scan](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507) plugin.

Keys
<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

Comment: Tags can be found "recursively".  We have our tags in a _tags/ folder at the source root.  `set tags=_tags/tags;c:/work` means "go up until you find something matching `_tags/tags`, but stop if you hit `c:/work`.  So if I'm editing c:/work/project/main/src/lib/subdir/file.c (from that file's directory) it can still find my tagfile c:/work/project/main/_tags/tags

Answer (score 4):

You probably know that once you're in vim, you can use

```
:cd lib/foo
```

to change into lib/foo.

On the other hand, to change into the directory of the file you're current editing, try

```
:cd %:p:h
```

You can always use

```
:pwd
```

to check your current working directory.

And of course, if you forgot what file you're editing, just hit ctrl-g.

Comment: can you explain :cd %:p:h

Comment: @EvanCarroll sure, It's explained here  https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file as "% gives the name of the current file, %:p gives its full path, and %:p:h gives its directory (the "head" of the full path)."

Answer (score 3):

On the "shortcut" front, have you looked into the `:Sex` command?  This opens up the file browser in a split so that you can open other files easily.  `:Sex` default to the directory of the current buffer.  Pretty nifty feature, if I say so myself.
I bind it to `;o` for easy access:

```
map ;o :Sex <CR>
```

You can also use `:Ex` if you want to keep it in the current buffer instead of creating a split.

Comment: awesome. I wish the file would open in the other pane though!

Comment: Oh, that's `:Ex`.  I'm in love with splits, so I think that way.  I'll edit the answer for it.

Comment: hehe no I know, what I meant is to keep the split, but when you open a file, it opens it in the other pane, not the file listing.

Comment: Sorry if this is too pedantic, but I think y'all mean "window" not "pane".

Answer (score 3):

I put this in my .vimrc file, which will change the current directory to the file in the buffer.  This sets the current directory for the buffer, and updates when you switch buffers.

```
autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h
```

Answer (score 3):

So vim has a :find command which will use the variable 'path'.  If you have consistent directory structures for your code such as all source in under a directory "src" then you can just add that to the 'path' variable.  Then when you do :find foo.js it will search both your current location then the folders listed in your path variable.  It basically emulates the way bash or some other shell uses the PATH variable to find the appropriate binary to run.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
:vs | Ex #open vertical split window
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to do:

```
:e <Tab>
```

This cycles through folders in your working directory.

Comment: This won't work, because my working directory isn't the one the file I'm editing is in.