# Open next file in VIM

Tags: vim, buffer

I have the following files in directory:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v149) 
"   /home/.../content
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$...
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../
./
.swo
1
10-1
10-2
10-3
10-4
10-5
10-6
2
3
4
5
6
7
8-1
8-2
8-3
9-1
9-2
9-3
9-4
9-5
```

Having `10-2` buffer opened, how can I open for editing the next file (`10-3`)?

What about going back?

Right now I do `:Ex` and then go to the next file.

Comment: Your question looks similar to please check this link -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708623/opening-files-in-the-same-folder-as-the-current-file-in-vim

Comment: Open all files: `vim *`. Then, use `:n` to go to the next file, and `:N` to go to the previous file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- My [EditSimilar plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2544) provides (among others) `:EditNext` and `:EditPlus` commands.
- [unimpaired.vim - Pairs of handy bracket mappings](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) includes a pair of `[f` / `]f` mappings to go to the previous / next file

Comment: Can I install it using Bundle?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: The GitHub repo for my plugin is https://github.com/vim-scripts/EditSimilar

Answer (score 3):

You can load all the files:

```
:args *
```

Then use `:bn` and `:bp` to switch.

EDIT: Okay, macro time... use these mappings:

```
nmap <leader>[ :Ex<CR>k<CR>
nmap <leader>] :Ex<CR>j<CR>
```

Note that this kind of depends on `<CR>` mapping from netrw, so you can't use `nnoremap`.

Comment: I only have one opened file for edit at the time. Having a lot of files loaded it not the best thing in my case.

Comment: Unless you're doing `:bd` after each file, I assure you that is not true. :) But yeah, if you have too many files, that's probably not the best idea.

Comment: Well, I meant that *I want to only have one opened buffer at the time*. :-) So, is there any workaround? Maybe a macro?

Comment: Can you explain that's the meaning of `<leader>`? Actually, I know that the default is `\`, but how can I find what its value in my case?  Also, what keys am I supposed to press to go to next/previous file?

Comment: `<leader>` is a key that is commonly used to prefix custom keybindings. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764263/what-is-the-leader-in-a-vimrc-file) for more info. If you haven't changed your mapleader, with these keybindings, two keys: `\[` for previous and `\]` for next. But there is nothing stopping you from changing those bindings to whatever you want.

Comment: Now the image is clearer and understand what these shortcuts do, but when I do `:Ex`, the cursor goes to the first file (not on the file that I was editing). How can I solve that?

Comment: Hmm, not in my Vim... And I tested on multiple systems, including those with no `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :setlocal bufhidden=wipe<CR>:edit<Space>
```

Action shot (the mapping is less polished but it does the same thing):

[image]

Comment: +1, but I only need simple shortcuts for doing that.

Comment: Which is exactly what I gave to you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the straight forward way to go about this is to put all files that you will need while working on your project in a buffer and move to the next or the previous buffer as you see fit.
For example: if you need three files at this time in your project:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Put all three files in the vim buffer with the following command:

```
vim file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

And open each buffer as you need with :bn to get the next buffer and :bp to get the previous buffer

```
:bn
:bp
```

(Optional) You can also open a new file in a buffer while you are editing a file in vim. The command is:

```
:e <name of the new file>
```

And then you can use :bn or :bp to get to the next or previous buffer